# Logical disjunction of checked checkbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Is there any way to make this work?

I have 4 checkboxes in jquery dialog, and each checkbox contains base64url code.
By closing dialog box, I'd like to get the new base64url code.

This is what I want to do.

1. search for checked checkbox
   (ex. select Layer1, Layer2, & Layer3)
2. convert each value from base64url to decimal
   (Layer1: 'gAAAAOAAAA' to '320000140000',
   Layer2: '*_*__BAIEI' to '636363636310848',
   Layer3: 'gAAAAAAADA' to '320000000030')
3. implement "OR" operation (logical disjunction)
   (1st decimal number of each layer is 32,63,32. so after OR operation, it is 63.)
4. convert the final value from decimal to base64url
   (Layer(final): '6363636363150878' to '*_*__PAIHI')

I did the 1st step as follows.

```
selected = [
 'gAAAAOAAAA',//Layer1
 '_____BAIEI',//Layer2
 'gAAAAAAADA',//Layer3
 'H-AAAgAEAA',//Layer4
];

$("#dialog").dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 modal: true,
 minWidth: 450,
 buttons:{
  "OK": function(){
   // search for checked checkboxes
   var checkList = [];
   $('[class="layer"]:checked').map(function(){
    var layerID = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
    var txt2 = selected[layerID];
    checkList.push(txt2);
   });
```

Can anyone please help me with the following steps?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented most of what you require [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3M2aF/1/).

```
var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';

function base64decode(str) {
    var bytes = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        bytes.push(alphabet.indexOf(str.charAt(i)));
    }

    return bytes;
}

function base64encode(bytes) {
    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        str += alphabet.charAt(bytes[i]);
    }

    return str;
}

$('input').click(
    function () {
        var values = [];
        var result = [];

        $('input:checked').each(
            function (_, el) { values.push(base64decode($(el).data('val'))); }
        );

        var result = [];

        if (values.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
                result.push(
                    values.reduce(
                        function (a, b) {
                            return a | b[i];
                        },
                        0
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        $('#result').text(base64encode(result));
    }
);
```

As an aside, I hold the Base64 encoded data inside a data attribute on each checkbox, rather than in a separate array.